# jquery width whole number, not decimal

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to take the value of a variable and use it for an element's width, but I want to drop the decimals from it and just have it be the whole number.  I got to here but can't seem to make it work

```
var grid_width= width:($(window).width() / 270)

$("#grid").css({
    width: grid_width.toFixed(0)
});
```

JS:

```
<script>

$('#grid').isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector : '.iso',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 270
  },
  animationEngine : 'jquery'
});



var grid_width = $(window).width() / 270;

$("#grid").css({
    width: Math.floor( grid_width ) + 'px',
    background: "green"
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var grid_width = $(window).width() / 270;

$("#grid").css({
    width: Math.floor( grid_width ) + 'px'
});
```

Comment: Returns the largest integer less than or equal to a number. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

Comment: I just added what I have for my script, the top part for the isotope seems to work fine, but the code for the rest doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Parse number to corresponding integer:

```
$("#grid").css({
    width: parseInt(grid_width)
});
```

Comment: I get this with that code I just added to the top.                                                    Problem at line 15 character 12: Missing radix parameter.
width: parseInt(width),

Implied global: $ 1,3,12,14, window 12